# IndentationError when running manage.py runserver Django

Tags: django, indentation

When I run `python manage.py runserver` on PowerShell, I got the following error:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py", line
__import__(name)
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

However, I have NEVER touched that file before and when I opened that file in Notepad++ it shows
this:

```
if name.startswith('.'):
    if not package:
        raise TypeError("relative imports require the 'package' argument")
    level = 0
    for character in name:
        if character != '.':
            break
        level += 1
    name = _resolve_name(name[level:], package, level)
    __import__(name)  #LINE 35
return sys.modules[name]`
```

What seems to be problematic? I am working on Windows Vista x32 with Python 2.7 and Django 1.4.2 
I appreciate your help.

Here's the database information under `settings.py`:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'demo',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': '****',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '*****',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '3306',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}
```

I also uncommented `'django.contrib.admin'` in same file. I uncommented `url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),`
in "urls.py" to enable admin. And here is the `urls.py` , which I got from `python manage.py startproject`

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
# Examples:
# url(r'^$', 'demo.views.home', name='home'),
# url(r'^demo/', include('demo.foo.urls')),

# Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
# url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

# Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

)

Comment: Deleted answer - I have no idea whats going on.

Comment: The problem is not in importlib, it's in whatever file importlib is trying to import. You mention changes to urls.py - you should probably post that.

Comment: I tried `python -m tabnanny -v <files>` for manage.py, settings.py, and urls.py and I got `Clean bill of health` so I think those files are alright.

Answer (score 1):

Using tab in Django is a bad practice. In order to fixed your problem you must use spaces only, I think 4 spaces. Try to backspace your codes and you'll see that it's tab indention, use only spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same error today.
Just like Dombey `python -m tabnanny -v *` reported a `Clean bill of health` for all my files.

I am using git so I tried running the master branch (which used to run fine) but I got the same result.

I don't know what triggered the error but uninstalling-reinstalling Django solved it for me.